# Remove function from file using sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command-line, sed

I want to remove the function `engine "map" { ... "foobar" ... }`.

I tried in so many ways, it's so hard because it has empty lines and '}' at the end, delimiters doesn't work

```
mainfunc {

  var = "baz"

  engine "map" {

    func {

      var0 = "foo"
      border = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
      var1 = "bar"
    }
  }
}

mainfunc {

  var = "baz"

  engine "map" {

    func {

      var0 = "foo"
      border = { 1, 1, 1, 1 }
      var1 = "foobar"
    }
  }
}

... # more functions like 'mainfunc'
```

I tried

```
sed '/engine/,/^\s\s}$/d' file
```

but removes every engine function, I just need the one containing "foobar", maybe a pattern match everything even newlines until foobar something like this:

```
sed '/engine(.*)foobar/,/^\s\s}$/d' file
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sed '/engine/{:a;N;/foobar/{N;N;d};/  }/b;ba}' filename
```

or:

```
awk '/engine/{c=1}c{b=b?b"\n"$0:$0;if(/{/)a++;if(/}/)a--;if(!a){if(b!~/foobar/)print b;c=0;b="";next}}!c' filename
```

Comment: Man, you rock!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would simple count the numbers of open / close brackets when you match `engine "map"`, cannot say if this only works in gawk

```
awk '
  /^[ \t]*engine "map"/ {
    ship=1; # ship is used as a boolean
    b=0 # The factor between open / close brackets
  }
  ship {
    b += split($0, tmp, "{"); # Count numbers of { in line
    b -= split($0, tmp, "}"); # Count numbers of } in line
    # If open / close brackets are equal the function ends
    if(b==0) { 
      ship = 0;
    }
    # Ship the rest (printing)
    next;
  }
  1 # Print line
' file
```

Split returns the number of matches: [`split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

> Divide
>   string into pieces defined by fieldpat
>   and store the pieces in array and the separator strings in the
>   seps array.  The first piece is stored in
>   `array[1]`, the second piece in `array[2]`, and so
>   forth.  The third argument, fieldpat, is
>   a regexp describing the fields in string (just as `FPAT` is
>   a regexp describing the fields in input records).
>   It may be either a regexp constant or a string.
>   If fieldpat is omitted, the value of `FPAT` is used.
>   `patsplit()` returns the number of elements created.